# WIX UI Installer Project in Visual Studio, Now Mange Updates?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, wix, upgrade

I have a fresh WIX UI Install project in VS which compiles down into an MSI.  Everything is working great with it.

It installs/uninstalls the files I want successfully.  For example, it drops 3 DLLs into a Program Files folder, installs a Windows Service, and GAC's a DLL.

Now let's say I install on this in a given environment.  Then one of our DLLs change and we need to upgrade this install without affecting other files already installed (such as the service)  So my thought would be I would need a patch/upgrade MSI that would target that one DLL and just overwrite that particular file.

What is the simplest way to accomplish this?  Do I need VS projects essentially for each patch/update MSI?  Below is my current 2 WIX related projects (installer + custom action)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For updating just the DLL a patch is recommended. Visual Studio doesn't support patches, but you can try using WiX: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/patch_building.htm

Please note that patches have some restrictions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367850(VS.85).aspx

A MSI which overwrites just one file is a bad mistake because you are not using the Windows Installer update mechanism.

If you want a MSI, it will have to be a [major upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). A major upgrade will automatically uninstall the old version before installing the current one.